# Using execute in subquery in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, dynamicquery

I am creating a dynamic query in my function from which I need to extract data.
now I want to execute that query.

something like this:

```
declare
df_id varchar;
BEGIN
/*creating dynamic query in run time and saving it in df_id in string format
say df_id='select col from schema.table_name**'*/
CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_table ON COMMIT DROP AS
    execute df_id;
```

How can I do this?
Also, Is there any other way that I can execute the query in string variable and store it to temp table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the `CREATE TABLE` in your dynamic SQL.

Assuming that the variable `df_id` already contains the `SELECT` statement, you can do something like this:

```
df_id := 'CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_table ON COMMIT DROP AS '||df_id;
execute df_id;
```

Comment: Thanks that worked.
Can I store this data in array also? if yes How? because in some cases I am not allowed to use temp table.

Comment: @VishalD: yes that's possible, but you should ask a new question for that. Do not extend the scope of your question once you have an answer